# Orthonormal Wavelet functions

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, wavelet-analysis

The wavelet function "WaveletPsi" is supposed to create an orthonormal basis of some space.

Now consider e.g. the following wavelet function:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
bas[shift_] := WaveletPsi[BattleLemarieWavelet[3, 5], x - shift];
```

Normality and orthogonality are not great but can be used for not too accurate work:

```
NIntegrate[bas[0] bas[0], {x, -10, 10}]
NIntegrate[bas[0] bas[1], {x, -10, 10}]

0.998881
0.00153636
```

But now consider the orthogonality of:

```
NIntegrate[bas[0] bas[3], {x, -10, 10}]

0.0100204
```

This is definitely not good enough. I hope I do not fool myself and someone can give an explanation.

Comment: Isn't this due the finite sampling interval of `BattleLemarieWavelet`? For example, if you increase the interval, e.g. `BattleLemarieWavelet[3, 20]`, the result is much better.

Comment: @ Domen  Thanks for your answer. I am not sure how to interpret  the parameter "lim". Dos MMA calculate the scaling function for a number of points, depending on "lim", and then fit and interpolating function through these points?

Comment: It looks like `WorkingPrecision` also greatly changes the behavior of `WaveletPsi` in this case. Changing `WorkingPrecision` to anything other than `MachinePrecision` seems to massively change `bas`

Comment: With `WorkingPrecision -> 32` it is even worse.

Comment: It sure "looks" like they are orthogonal: `Manipulate[
 Plot[{bas[i], bas[j]}, {x, -10, 10},  
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Orange, Blue}}}, PlotRange -> All],
 {i, Range[10]}, {j, Range[10]}
 ]`.  I thought it might be insufficient sampling for the InterpolatingFunction that WaveletPsi produces.  `MaxRecursion -> 8` makes it worse too.

Comment: `MinRecursion->6` doesn't help either.  I don't know if this is interesting or not, but this inner products appear to produce a Toeplitz matrix: `Outer[NIntegrate[#1 #2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, MinRecursion -> 6, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 20] &, bas /@ Range[0, 8], 
  bas /@ Range[0, 8]] // MatrixForm`

Comment: The sampling for the interpolating function seems coarse to me. I can't see any options to make that finer. `bas[1][[1, 1, 1, 0, 3]]`

Comment: Ummm, thinking about it…. Of course it’s Toeplitz. Palm slap to forehead.